# ruby on rails syntax error with match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, match

When creating my application using ROR, I continually receive a syntax error when I use:

```
FitsbyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

I am using Rails 3.2.8. Could it be that I don't have the right version of Rails or Ruby?

This is the error I get when I run the match:

> rb:245:in `load':
>   /Users/dannygaeta/rails_projects/fitsby_app/config/routes.rb:2: syntax
>   error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)

I get this for each match. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is (probably) from the trailing colon in `to:`. That said, I'm no rails expert but shouldn't the route in question look like this?

```
match '/help' => 'static_pages#help'
```

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: The `key: value` syntax only works in Ruby 1.9 or greater. The `to` syntax is perfectly valid, but will need to use `:to => static_pages#help` in Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you're using ruby 1.8.x. Ruby 1.9 introduced a new syntax for hashes,

```
match 'foo', to: 'bar'
```

Is the same as

```
match 'foo', :to => 'bar'
```

Your routes file appears to be using the newer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3:

`match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout`

OR

`match '/help' => 'static_pages#help'`

In Rails 4:

match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout, via: [:get, :post]